# How to edit the SQL Agent Job from within SSMS 2005?

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, edit, sql-server-agent

I am trying to edit or view the SQL Agent's job (I am the owner of this job) from SSMS 2005 and I can't find out how to do this. When I am double-clicking a job or entering job's properties I get empty "New Job" window.

Is there some way to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem a while back.  I'm not entirely sure what caused it, but the fix was installing sp2 of sql server onto my local machine (or whichever machine you're using ssms on).  the only documentation i found at the time suggested that that was the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can genereate SQL Script for SQL Job and then edit it. right click the job and then
click generate SQL Script. Here you can also change the job properties with the sql sciript

Comment: Yes I did so already but I need some simple way to look inside a job. It seems to me that it is some sort of bug maybe.

Comment: In that case, I don't know what the problem would be. Try, with a new service, setting the properties after the properties dialog shows up empty. See if it can even persist what it shows. In any case, get on latest Service Packs, and if it still happens, either call Microsoft Support, or report it at http://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver/.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new job explicitly, then try editing your new job the same way and see what happens.

In particular, it's possible that your old job really *is* empty.

Comment: No the job is not empty. I have about 20 jobs and all of them are active and working. And this problem happens with all jobs.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your issue with SSMS is. Maybe you dont have permission? 
Unless your sa you need to be a member of the SQLAgentOperatorRole  in MSDB?

If you can still run queries then look at the *sysjobs* and *sysjobsteps* tables in the MSDB database, this has all the properties
You can use the [*sp_update_job*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188745.aspx) to modify the job